# Pipe output of python script

Tags: python, terminal, piping

I'm running `./sample.py --url http://blah.com` without error, though if I run `./sample.py --url http://blah.com | wc -l` or similar I receive an error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200f' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

How do I make a python script compatible with my terminal commands? I keep seeing reference to `sys.stdin.isatty` though its use case appears to be opposite.

Comment: What does sample.py look like? Are you just doing normal `print` statements?

Comment: You might try using xargs:  `./sample.py --url http://blah.com | xargs wc -l`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Python detects that it is printing to a terminal, `sys.stdout.encoding` is set to the encoding of the terminal. When you `print` a `unicode`, the `unicode` is encoded to a `str` using the `sys.stdout.encoding`.

When Python does not detect that it is printing to a terminal, `sys.stdout.encoding` is set to `None`. When you `print` a `unicode`, the `ascii` codec is used (at least in Python2). This will result in a UnicodeError if the `unicode` contains code points outside of 0-127.

One way to fix this is to explicitly encode your `unicode` before printing. That perhaps is the proper way, but it can be laborious if you have a lot of print statements scattered around.

Another way to fix this is to set the [PYTHONIOENCODING](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to an appropriate encoding. For example,

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Then this encoding will be used instead of `ascii` when printing output to a file.

See the [PrintFails wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for that @unutbu. Thought #1 - follow [this article](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python) from now on. #2 - Where is the right place to put this line for now?

Comment: @mjb: How you should set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable depends on the machine's OS. It is done the same way as you set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. On Linux, you could put `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @mjb: for a single command in bash: `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 ./sample.py ...`. btw, User-perceived characters and codepoints are different things, though it is a topic for another article

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
(./sample.py --url http://blah.com) | wc -l
```

This spawns a subshell to run your python script then pipes the output from `stdout` to `wc`

Comment: It won't work, try `(  python -c 'print(u"tra\u00eetre")'  )  | wc -l`

Comment: py file can only be executed with python interpretor at the start of sample.py