# Python script prints unicode, use in shell ` ` causes error

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, unicode

I have a Python script called a.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u''
```

In both bash and tcsh:

```
$ a.py
Ô£øÔ£øÔ£øÔ£ø
$ echo `a.py`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 3, in <module>
    print u'Ô£øÔ£øÔ£øÔ£ø'
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error is coming from Python, not the shell. How can running the script under backticks affect the script itself? Note that this is not a problem if I switch the interpreter to Python 3 at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When Python does not detect that it is printing to a terminal, as is the case when in a subshell, sys.stdout.encoding is set to None. When you print a unicode, the ascii codec is used (at least in Python2). This will result in a UnicodeError if the unicode contains code points outside of 0-127.

A way to fix this is to set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable to an appropriate encoding. For example:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8; echo `a.py`
```

Credits for this go to [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481582/pipe-output-of-python-script/13481729#answer-13481729)!

Comment: Wow. I never would have figured this out. So I tried adding this to a.py: import os
os.putenv('PYTHONIOENCODING', 'utf-8')
but that doesn't work. Probably my lack of experience with bash (I mostly use tcsh), but I don't understand why your solution works but this doesn't.